# flutter pub get failed during flutter create

Tags: flutter

Hi my friend is trying to create a new app but he is not able to create it.

**Error**

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Running "flutter pub get" in myapp...
pub get failed (1)
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.4, on Windows, locale en-IL)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.4 at C:\Users\gurko\flutter
    • Framework revision cc949a8e8b (3 weeks ago), 2019-09-27 15:04:59 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: add `-v` to your `flutter create` command, what do you see now?

Comment: ץץץ
Try moving -v to be immediately following create
***
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28:3)
#1      CreateCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:307:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:490:18)
#3      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:71:64)
#4      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#5      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)

Comment: can you explain with more details what to do? thanx

Comment: it is clearly written: "Try moving **-v** to be immediately following **create**"

Comment: again refuse to work: https://pastebin.com/ydTHMeQi https://pastebin.com/vNcumEvF hope for help

Comment: and did you do `cd myapp` and then `flutter run`?

Comment: yes he did please lock at the pastbin links: https://pastebin.com/vNcumEvF  https://pastebin.com/ydTHMeQi

Comment: it says: `In order to run your application, type:
 
             $ cd myapp
             $ flutter run
 
` did you do that?

Comment: yes he did it
https://pastebin.com/vNcumEvF
log

Comment: did you see `"Crash report written to C:\Users\gurko\Documents\myapp\flutter_03.log"`? whats inside?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r4eqfBGP

Comment: my  friend said that the file already exist

Comment: please need help !!

Answer (score 1):

- Check all the environment variables (JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME etc.) and path are set properly
- Type `$flutter doctor --android-licenses`
- It might say some licenses are not accepted(something like that) you
  will be asked
- 'Do you want to review the licenses'?
- Type `y<press enter>`
- Accept all the licenses review.
- Now check flutter again with `$flutter doctor`